# Align multiline equation in bold font

Tags: horizontal-alignment, equations, align, bold

I want to align an equation:

```
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\end{align*}
```

Which works. But having it in `\mathbf{}`:

```
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{a &= b}\\
c &= d
\end{align*}
```

gives me an error.

Of course, I could end the `\mathbf` at `&=` and apply it afterwards, but is there an easier way? (I have long and complicated equations)

Answer (score 2):

you can use `\boldmath`, but be careful -- this will make *all* math within its
scope bold:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
text $a + b$.
\boldmath
text $a + b$.
\begin{align*}
a &= b\\
c &= d
\end{align*}
\unboldmath
text $a + b$.
\end{document}
```

[image: output of example code]

you can also limit the scope by placing the intended material within braces.

Comment: ,@barbarabeeton -- I think the OP asks for a single line within the `align` environment to be in bold math, and not to repeat `\mathbf`, did I understand the question correctly?

Comment: @AboAmmar -- i may have misunderstood the question.  if the op confirms that, i will delete this answer, since `\boldmath` can be used only *outside* a math environment.

Answer (score 1):

The error in your example is because the alignment markers `&` only work inside the same group. So, the easiest solution may be to locally bold the symbols you want using the `bm` package (better than `\mathbf{...}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
  \bm a &=\bm b\\
  c     &=    d
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

> [image]