# Creating Bold Equations in align Environment

Tags: equations, formatting

Suppose I have a series of equations that I want aligned using the `align` environment, but I want the last equation to be bold. When I use `\pmb` to make the equation bold, the `&` symbol isn't recognized inside the `\pmb` command and throws an error.

How could I make the last equation bold and keep it aligned with the previous equations? A code example is below. I have tried using both the \bm and \boldmath packages (mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/354620/align-multiline-equation-in-bold-font)), and neither one works. (The \bm actually destroys the fraction). I'm using ShareLatex, and the equation is in a Beamer document. Code snippet:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{align*}
0 &\leq 2 \sigma - (k+2) \\
\frac{k}{2} + 1 &\leq \sigma
\end{align*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of posting code snippets, provide a full document, please. `\pmb` ('poor man's bold') is a means of last resort...

Comment: Question updated to include a full document sample. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
\begin{align*}
0 &\leq 2 \sigma - (k+2) \\
\boldsymbol{\frac{k}{2} + 1 }&\boldsymbol{\leq \sigma}
\end{align*}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Not too elegant ... but works.

Answer (score 3):

A hack is hooking into `\@lign` that is executed in each cell before entering math mode.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{environ}

\makeatletter
\NewEnviron{specialalign*}{%
  \appto\@lign{\specialalign@row}%
  \gdef\specialalign@row{\mathversion{normal}}%
  \begin{align*}
  \BODY
  \end{align*}
}
\newcommand{\normalrow}{%
  \noalign{\gdef\specialalign@row{\mathversion{normal}}}%
}
\newcommand{\boldrow}{
  \noalign{\gdef\specialalign@row{\mathversion{bold}}}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{specialalign*}
0 &\leq 2 \sigma - (k+2) \\
\boldrow
\frac{k}{2} + 1 &\leq \sigma \\
\frac{k}{2} + 1 &\leq \sigma \\
\normalrow
\frac{k}{2} + 1 &\leq \sigma
\end{specialalign*}

\end{document}
```

As you see you can alternate between bold and normal rows.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the `bm` package to do this, but the `&` symbol for aligment cannot be contained in the `\bm{}` environment, like so :

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}

\begin{align*}
0 &\leq 2 \sigma - (k+2) \\
\bm{\frac{k}{2} + 1 }&\bm{\leq \sigma}
\end{align*}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output :

[image]